# Fitting LPPL model using R

Tags: r, regression, econometrics, nls

apologies if this appears too simplistic/poorly worded a question, this is my first time coding in R

I am attempting to fit the LPPL model to a price series in order to test for its predictive power for financial crashes. As I understand the difficulty in fitting the model is due to the number of variables leading to multiple local minima. So far I have attempted to fit the model using the nls.lm function, my code is below:

```
# Dataset import #
mydata<-fread("data.csv", sep="," , header=TRUE)

# Creating function object #
f <- function(pars, xx) 
   with(pars,(a + b*(tc - xx)^m * (1 + c * cos(omega*log(tc - xx) + phi))))`

resids <- function(p, observed, xx) {mydata$Logp - f(p,xx)}

# Fitting using Levenberg-Marquardt Algorithm #
nls.out <- nls.lm(par=list(a=1,b=-1,tc=100, m=0.5, omega=1, phi=1, c=1 ),
          fn = resids, observed = mydata$Logp, xx = mydata$day,
          control=nls.lm.control(maxiter=10000, ftol=1e-6, maxfev=1e6))
```

However the fit for this model is still poor and irrespective of how I alter the starting parameters it fails to predict a crash occurring one day later with any degree of accuracy. This is troublesome as the data I have fitted the model to has been successfully modelled using the LPPL model in numerous papers.

I have seen in other papers that those using the LM algorithm first use a Tabu Search to identify sensible starting parameters, however I am not sure how to go about doing this.

From what I have read online I also believe using the rgenoud package is a more powerful global optimiser tool. However I am not able to generate the correct code to run the package successfully.

Any help in doing so would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Read more of the LPPL literature, first, you need to do some fancy trig to remove the phi term from the nl optimization space.  After, you do this your phi and omega terms won't have an interdependence and any nl optimization algorithm should do the trick.  Otherwise try a particle swarm.